# How to get the timestamp value of an entry when it is added to cache in ehcache3?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache-3

while migrating from ehcache 2.10to 3.5.2, can not find replacement for
"net.sf.ehcache.Element" in ehcache 3.5.2 version.

Following is the code in ehacache2 version :

```
Element pageCacheElement = basicCache.getQuiet(filepath);
long pageTime = pageCacheElement.getValue().getTimestamp();
```

As **net.sf.ehcache.Element** removed in ehacache 3 version,how to get the timestamp value when retrieving an element from cache.

Any help would be appreciated.